# the style does not change ( help needed in media query ! )

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

i've been trying to make an image to the center of the screen and minimize the size in mobile display! in my css file i've the media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
.wolver { display:block; width:100px; margin:40px auto !important;}
}
```

the HTML code for the image is

```
<img src="img/icons/wolverhampton.png" class="wolver"/>
```

Note: I am using foundation framework

Could anyone help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

`min-width` will apply the contained styles on screens **wider** than 768px. To apply the css on screens smaller than 768px you should be using `max-width`.

Comment: thanks mate ! i am new to media queries , thanks for finding out the mistake .. !